# Mongodb hosting remote vs on the same network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hosting, shared-hosting

What is the killer reason to use remote db hostring services for MongoDB (like compose.io) for nodejs application VS hosting MongoDB on the same network (in the same datacenter, etc), for example when using PAAS providers (like modulus.io) which offer "integrated" MongoDB hosting .

What percentage of speed/perfomance may degrade when using internet remote DBs, how do DB providers you solve this? How to make right decision on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you use something like compose.io is that you don't want to deal with that on your own and have experts taking care of it that know what they are doing. In the best case with support so you can take further advantage of those experts. And that's the only reason.

If you use Modulus that has this anyway and you run your application there as well - even better. There is no real reason to run your node application on Modulus and your mongodb on a different cloud hosting service.

In practice that probably doesn't matter as much because they all use AWS anyway ;)

Important: If they DON'T run in the same network make sure your mongoDB is protected properly(!!). If you do run in the same network just make sure the mongoDB is not accessible from the outside at all which is def the better solution!

Hope that helps